# How to get current RAM price inside a contract in C++?

Tags: smart-contract, ram, c++, eosio-code

How can I programatically get the current(last) RAM price inside an EOS smart contract in C++?
I need to handle the data inside the smart contract for an experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to eosio.system and find the exchange_state.hpp, there's a table rammarket for the information, but I can't give you the formula now, you can investigate into it.

Comment: I need the code example to accept this answer, it will also help others

Comment: hope others can help you, but my suggestion is the way

Comment: I'm a c++ noob just like many other who learn it just for eos so I need a more complete answer. I'll post the solution as soon as I find it though.